# c# webbrowser navigate loop freezing form

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to display a website in a form and automatically reload the website to see if a certain text is present. I'm doing this in a C# form and try to call a while with an button. This is the code I made:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();       
    }

    private void btnStartLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatusLoop.Text = "Status loop: Started";
        lblStatusLoop.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10)
        {
            Browser.Navigate("www.google.com");
            Browser.DocumentCompleted += Browser_DocumentCompleted;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            i++;
        }
    }

    void Browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ZoekText = txtSearchbox.Text.ToString();
        if (Browser.DocumentText.Contains(ZoekText))
        {
            lblSearchResult.Text = "Text found";
        }
        else
        {
            lblSearchResult.Text = "Text not found";
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I push the button the appliction freezes and I have to force quit it. I've done some research on google and suggestions were to wait for the document to complete loading but it has no effect.

I don't have much programming experience and do not have someone to fall back on so I hope someone here can point me into right direction.

Comment: Well Thread.Sleep(5000) will block the user interface for 5 seconds ... Its unclear what you want to do, reloading the next url at the end of Browser_DocumentCompleted would perhaps be wiser.

Comment: Thread.sleep(5000) called 10 times will effectively cause the application to hang for 50 seconds...

Comment: You only need to add the event handler for DocumentCompleted once. Take that outside of your loop.

Comment: Perhaps you should call the next navigate to google.com during your document complete and have an if check to see if a class variable is less than 10.

Comment: Also, unless that web browser control is running in a separate STA thread from your main form, I don't think you will actually get to see it navigate until your loop finishes. So my suggestion is to do what I said in my previous comment.